# How to order in exact time of creation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, Course, which `has_many tees`. The tees are created individuall from a hash derived from an api e.g

```
  course_h[:tees].each do |tee_h|
    course.tees.create!(tee_h)
  end
```

Later I retrieve another hash and want to compare the new hash with the saved tees. I would like to have the same order as the original hash, and assumed that I could do this with `course.tees.order(created_at: :asc)`. This works in the test environment, but in development environment, the order is not the same.  Why is this, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I would add an extra field for this, `sort` or `position`, whatever you like.

Comment: On a lot of databases the precision on insertion times is 1s, so inserting a bunch of records quickly might result in identical insertion times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tempting to use the object id for this purpose but as noted in the comments, the ordering of the object id or the created_at field cannot be relied upon.  It is safer to add an ordering field, say :num. The code would then be

course_h[:tees].each_with_index do |tee_h, i|
  Tee.create!(tee_h.merge(num: i)
end
and then use the ordering `course.tees.order(num: asc)`